# How to convert enum string value to variable?

Tags: string, variables, enums

So lets say I have this enum

```
public enum StatType
{
Strength, Dexterity, Intelligence, Wisdom, Luck
}
```

and I have this function,

```
public void SetStats(StatType type, int value)
{
    switch (type)
    {
            case StatType.Strength:
            hero.Stats.Strength += value;
            break;
            case StatType.Dexterity:
            hero.Stats.Dexterity += value;
            break;
            case StatType.Intelligence:
            hero.Stats.Intelligence += value;
            break;
            case StatType.Wisdom:
            hero.Stats.Wisdom += value;
            break;
            case StatType.Luck:
            hero.Stats.Luck += value;
            break;
    } 
}
```

How can I change this incoming stat's "type" parameter to hero.Stats.(  ) variable's name?

If this is possible, then I don't need to use switch, right?

Comment: you could do that using reflection, but it would make the program rather more complex. Your code is fine as is. And yes, with reflection you could make it without `switch`

Comment: @nandsito Thx, ok I see. Then I should satisfied with this.